# How to declare type in this kind of situation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to declaring type for a button.
Button will display or not display according to the return result.

This thing is i don't know how to declare this kind of type where it got many return properties.

This code for footer button is for default return

```
interface footerButton{
  text: string;
  isEnabled: boolean;
}

function mapStateToProps(
  state: AppState
): LessonDrawerStateProps {
  let footerButton: footerButton | undefined << here is the problem
 }

footerButton = (completedLessonIds.size > 1 && !currentUser) && {
        text: "Save your progress",
        isEnabled: true,
     };


return { footerButton: footerButton }
```

As you can see i am declaring the type of footer button inside the `mapStateToProps`

when I define it as `footerButton: footerButton | undefined`

this program is giving me this error

```
Type 'false | { text: string; isEnabled: true; }' is not assignable to type 'footerButton | undefined'.
```

So I change it to `footerButton: footerButton | boolean`

```
Type 'boolean | footerButton' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; isEnabled: boolean; } | undefined'.
```

this program give me another error?
So How can i delclare in this kind of situation

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), and where the only issues with the code are the ones you're asking about.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface footerButton{
  text: string;
  isEnabled: boolean;
}

function mapStateToProps(
  state: AppState
): LessonDrawerStateProps {
  let footerButton: footerButton | undefined
 }

  if (completedLessonIds.size > 1 && !currentUser) {
    footerButton = {
      text: "Save your progress",
      isEnabled: true,
    };
  }


return { footerButton: footerButton }
```

This should work.

So, what the problem? When you do use such expression

```
 footerButton = (completedLessonIds.size > 1 && !currentUser) && {
    text: "Save your progress",
    isEnabled: true,
 };
```

and the condition is not pass, you will get false. This false is not a boolean actually. It cannot be true, only false.
But if you will change code as I did above, you will have undefined or your object as you wanted initially.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is being displayed but you only want it to in certain circumstances, try a variable and an if(){} statement. Create a boolean variable (like buttonShow or something) and whenever you want the button to show, you can use the if statement. Sort of like this :

```
var buttonShow = false;

interface footerButton{
  text: string;
  isEnabled: boolean;
}

function mapStateToProps(
  state: AppState
): LessonDrawerStateProps {
  if(buttonShow){
  let footerButton: footerButton 
  }
 }

footerButton = (completedLessonIds.size > 1 && !currentUser) && {
        text: "Save your progress",
        isEnabled: true,
     };


return { footerButton: footerButton }
```

Or else, you could try typing null so that the undefined error won't pop up. if you don't give things a value it will jump to undefined. but if you say for example "var random = null;", then you won't get the error.

Good luck!